# Images do not work in next.js with netlify

Tags: next.js, netlify

I have a next.js site uploaded to Netlify. The site is connected to a custom domain. I recently upgraded the site from next.js 11 to 12. On Netlify's end I just upgraded from @netlify/plugin-nextjs@3.9.2 to 4.34.0. Netlify proves a default domain and the images load just fine on that. However, on the custom domain, the images do not load properly. This was not the case one year ago on the older versions of next and Netlify. I have not touched the site in a year.

In the console for my site, I get this error for all the images:

```
GET https://customdomain.com/nextimg/%2Fimages%2FHomepage%2Fhomepage_slideshow_3.jpg/828/100?url=%2Fimages%2FHomepage%2Fhomepage_slideshow_3.jpg&w=828&q=100 404
```

Interestingly, in the the network tab the default domain loads the following URL: `https://defaultdomain.netlify.app/_ipx/w_828,q_100/%2Fimages%2FHomepage%2Fhomepage_slideshow_2.jpg?url=%2Fimages%2FHomepage%2Fhomepage_slideshow_2.jpg&w=828&q=100`
and my custom domain loads the following url:
`https://customdomain.com/nextimg/%2Fimages%2FHomepage%2Fhomepage_slideshow_2.jpg/828/100?url=%2Fimages%2FHomepage%2Fhomepage_slideshow_2.jpg&w=828&q=100`
The default domain loads it form `/_ipx` whereas the custom domain loads it from `/nextimg`.

After going through the build logs I get the following statement:

```
6:48:05 PM: Netlify configuration property "redirects" value changed to [
6:48:05 PM:   { from: '/_next/static/*', to: '/static/:splat', status: 200 },
6:48:05 PM:   {
6:48:05 PM:     from: '/_next/image*',
6:48:05 PM:     query: { url: ':url', w: ':width', q: ':quality' },
6:48:05 PM:     to: '/_ipx/w_:width,q_:quality/:url',
6:48:05 PM:     status: 301
6:48:05 PM:   },
6:48:05 PM:   { from: '/_ipx/*', to: '/.netlify/builders/_ipx', status: 200 },
```

There are many more redirects, but I believe these to be relevant. The default domain seems to follow the redirects, whereas the custom domain does not. I do not see why this should be the case. Is there a fix to making the images load on my custom domain?

Some things I tried:

- I attemped to make a custom `netlify.toml` file and add only my redirects, but Netlify imposes the shown redirects anyway.
- The images are stored in a public directory in my root folder, not an external website. I still attempted to add my custom domain to the next.config.js file. This failed.
- I tried to deploy the site through the CLI using `netlify build` and `netlify deploy`, because I figured maybe my auto deploys from git are the issue, but this failed miserably. The site had no content and the whole thing was just white.
- I tried forcing node.js version `16.20.0` (I do not know what Netlify uses by default), but this changed nothing.
- I tried setting `NEXT_FORCE_EDGE_IMAGES=true`, but this changed nothing.
- I tried switching `next/image` to the regular html `img` tag. This worked, but I want `next/image` and this switch should not be necessary.
- Frankly, literally everything I thought could remotely work. It is probably some niche setting or something super obvious that I have missed.

Comment: Running into a similar issue here. Did you find a resolution Eshy?

Answer (score 0):

tldr; Clear your local browser cache. ‍♂️

Your browser most likely cached the redirect from /_next/image to the old /nextimg/… optimised image URL. Since no images exist at /nextimg due to the [upgrade to ipx in 2021](https://github.com/netlify/next-runtime/pull/583), the image returned a 404 error.

Once we cleared the cache, any new requests were passing straight through to Netlify which could then generate the new /_ipx/… URL which our browser then nicely caches again using the correct redirect URL.

In Chrome, you can quickly disable the cache here to test it's this:
[image]